# Adding a new node to the end of a linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to add a new node to the end of a linked list in C, but I'm having trouble with my code.
here is what I tried

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
  int data;
  struct node *next;
};

struct node *head = NULL;

void add_node(int data) {
  struct node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  new_node->data = data;
  new_node->next = NULL;

  if (head == NULL) {
    head = new_node;
  } else {
    struct node *current = head;
    while (current->next != NULL) {
      current = current->next;
    }
    current->next = new_node;
  }

  int *x = NULL;
  *x = 5;
}

int main() {
  add_node(5);

  return 0;
}
```

However, when I try to run this code, I get a segmentation fault. Can someone help me figure out what's going wrong?
I've tried debugging the code by adding print statements, but I'm not sure where the problem is occurring. I've also tried double-checking that I've correctly allocated memory for the new node using malloc.

Comment: This code doesn't 'run'. there is no `main`, and nothing that calls `add_node`. Post a proper [mcve].

Comment: It works fine for me adding a couple of nodes (i.e. not reproducible).  Unrelated, I suggest you pass in the head instead of using a global variable.

Comment: OT: is the indent only 2 for any special reason. Code is much more readable with an indent of 4.

Comment: Not quite the same function in the reposted version... What's the business with `*x` doing?

Comment: Really??? What's the point of the last two lines that you added in the edit, other than to create a segfault?

Comment: sorry! I forgot to copy the whole code from editor.

Answer (score 1):

In your updated code you deference the pointer `x` which you previously set to NULL.  Eliminate the junk code, or if you must you make `x` point at an integer:

```
int *x = &(int) {0};
*x = 5;
```

I suggest you eliminate the global variable along these lines:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

void add_node(struct node **head, int data) {
    struct node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if(!new_node) {
       // handle error
       return;
    }
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = NULL;
    if (!*head) {
        *head = new_node;
        return;
    }
    struct node *current = *head;
    for(;current->next; current = current->next);
    current->next = new_node;
}

int main() {
    struct node *head = NULL;
    add_node(&head, 5);
}
```

Comment: @Fe2O3 Likewise!